# Splitting a string with a comma as delimiter

Tags: vba, excel

I need a text box where you enter a name and it then separates the name into a first and last name and displays it in 2 text boxes. It must support entry in the form of "FIRST LAST" and "LAST, FIRST".

I have the FIRST LAST done.

This is what I have for the LAST, FIRST:

```
Private Sub inputText_Change()

End Sub

Private Sub Label1_Click()

End Sub

Private Sub retrieveinput_Click()
FullName = inputText.Text
Dim NameArray() As String

If FullName.Contains(",") Then
    NameArray = Split(FullName, ",")
    First = NameArray(1)
    Last = NameArray(0)
Else
    NameArray = Split(FullName)
    First = NameArray(0)
    Last = NameArray(1)
End If

TextBox2.Text = First
TextBox3.Text = Last

End Sub
```

This is giving an error that says "Object Required" at

```
If FullName.Contains(",") Then
```

Comment: `names = FullName.Split(","c)`

Comment: Okay, that takes care of the splitting. What would the if statement look like then? Because the case would be if the name contains a comma, split it and proceed, else do what we already have completed.

Comment: you already have that.  if it contains a comma, split on it and reverse the order otherwise split on the space and dont reverse.

Comment: You don't have to handle every case, but you should at least be aware of [Falsehoods programmers believe about names](http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/).

Comment: [edit] your post with the relevant code and *where* you get the error. comments are for teasing out details

Comment: if you have 2 TBs reserved for first and last, why not use them? You didnt say where you get the error

Comment: I am going to take a moderately wild guess and say that you get the error on `FullName.Contains(",")`.  If that is the case, you are not using VB.NET but something else, maybe VB6.  Those even signatures are not correct for .NET

Comment: im using VB on excel macros and yes thats where im getting the error

Comment: I need to fix this:                    If FullName.Contains(",") Then

Comment: You may want to [edit] the question to remove the [tag:vb.net] tag and add the [tag:vba] tag if it's really an excel macro.

Answer (score 1):

VBA code:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub retrieveinput_Click()
    Dim nameArray As Variant, full As String, first As String, last As String

    full = inputText.Text

    If Len(full) > 0 Then                   'if not empty

        nameArray = Split(full, ",")        'attempt to split on comma

        If UBound(nameArray) < 1 Then       'if comma doesn't exist (1 element in array)

            nameArray = Split(full)         'attempt to split by space (" ")

            If UBound(nameArray) > 0 Then   'if at least one space exists
                first = nameArray(0)        'FIRST_1 FIRST_2 LAST doesn't work
                last = nameArray(1)         'multiple last names won't work either
            Else
                first = full                'one word only
            End If
        Else                                'comma exists so last name is first in array
            first = Trim(nameArray(1))      'remove first space after comma
            last = Trim(nameArray(0))
        End If
    End If
    TextBox2.Text = first
    TextBox3.Text = last

    'Debug.Print "First Name: """ & first & """, Last Name: """ & last & """"

    'Input 1: ""                            -> First Name: "", Last Name: ""
    'Input 2: "FIRST LAST"                  -> First Name: "FIRST", Last Name: "LAST"
    'Input 3: "LAST, FIRST"                 -> First Name: "FIRST", Last Name: "LAST"
    'Input 4: "FIRST1 FIRTS2 LAST1 LAST2"   -> First Name: "FIRST1", Last Name: "FIRTS2"
    'Input 5: "FIRST"                       -> First Name: "FIRST", Last Name: ""
End Sub
```